# How to recreate this header in the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As in the image below I have a column header in the 5th column with rotated text. I am only concerned with that one.

[image]

The XAML so far is this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="rotatedTextStart" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value><RotateTransform Angle="-45" /></Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="rotatedTextMiddle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value><RotateTransform Angle="-45" /></Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-50,0,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="rotatedTextEnd" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value><RotateTransform Angle="-45" /></Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-50,0,12,0"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="{x:Null}" DataContext="{StaticResource UserGroups}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Title" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" Binding="{Binding Path=Job_Title}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" Binding="{Binding Path=Department}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}"/>

        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}" CanUserResize="False" Width="580">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Modules</TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextStart}" >Customer Services</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Asset Management</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Works Management</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Project Management</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Rates Management</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Finance</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Human Resources</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Document Management</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >User Management</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextEnd}" >Configuration</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have a List<module> called _modules, module has the following properties:

```
public class Module
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public string ModuleColor { get; set; }
    public bool ModuleAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

e.g.: ModuleName = "Customer Services"

What I am trying figure out is how to create the same rotated header by binding the _modules List to some type of control. What control should I use?

[Edit] After shifting to a listview and commenting out the stackpanel with textblocks

```
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}" CanUserResize="False" Width="580">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Modules</TextBlock>
            <!--
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextStart}" >Customer Services</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Asset Management</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Works Management</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Project Management</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Rates Management</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Finance</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Human Resources</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >Document Management</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" >User Management</TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextEnd}" >Configuration</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            -->
            <ListView Width="190">
                <ListViewItem>kjh</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>kjh</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: You should apply `rotatedTextMiddle` style to the control

Comment: Thanks @AndreyGordeev any ideas on what type of Control I can use to bind the List with?

Comment: Really I thought you had to have some sort of control with repetitive items like a datagrid or listview?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I musunderstood you. To bind a `List` use `GridView` or `ListView`. I meant, you can use `TextBlock` for column headers

Comment: Thanks you need to put this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind `_modules` to `GridView` or `ListView`. Use `TextBlock`'s with `rotatedTextMiddle` style applied for column headers

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstModules" Width="190" ItemsSource="{Binding _modules}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource rotatedTextMiddle}" Text="{Binding ModuleName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: So if I use a ListView, which I am trying now, how do I get the items to display horizontally?

Comment: They should display horisontally by default, actually

Comment: I just added in an edit to the top post, to show what I've tried and an image of what it looks like.

Comment: Do you want to put `_modules` in the header or in the body?

Comment: _modules will go in the header.

Comment: See my edited answer. Make sure `_modules` is a public property